# Keeping a jar file from terminating on repl.it

Tags: discord.py, replit

I'm trying to host a music bot on repl.it and lavalink keeps terminating on. How do I stop it from terminating.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem for a few weeks. The solution is very simple.

```
import os
import time
import threading

def run_lavalink():
  os.system("java -jar Lavalink.jar")

threading.Thread(target=run_lavalink).start()
time.sleep(20) #wait until lavalink is ready up

#bot.run and other stuffs
```